# Finding if a point is in a polygon

Tags: javascript, math, google-maps-api-3, coordinates

I have this code here that is attempting to work out if a point `latLng` passes through a polygon `Maps.area`.

```
Maps.ui.contains = function(latLng){
    //poly.getBounds gets the 'box' around the polygon
    if(!Maps.ui.getBounds().contains(latLng))
        return false;
    //So we dont need to check t/f, we either set it or we dont
    var inPolygon = false;
    var count = 0;

    Maps.area.getPaths().forEach(function(el0, index0){
        var last = el0.getLength() - 1;
        el0.forEach(function(el1, index1){
            count += Maps.ui.ray_intersect_segment(latLng, el1, el0.getAt(last));
            last = index1; 
        });
    });

    if(Maps.area.getPaths().getLength()%2 == 0)
        return count%2==0;
    else
        return count%2!=0;


}

var eps = 0.0001;
var inf = 1e600;
Maps.ui.ray_intersect_segment = function(point, i1, i2){
    var p = point;
    var segment = (i1.lng() > i2.lng())?[i2, i1]:[i1, i2];

    p = (p.lng() == segment[0].lng() || p.lng() == segment[1].lng())?new google.maps.LatLng(p.lng() + eps):p;

    if(p.lng() < segment[0].lng() || p.lng() > segment[1].lng() || p.lat() > [segment[0].lat(), segment[1].lng()].max())
        return 0;
    if(p.lat() < [segment[0].lat(), segment[1].lat()].min())
        return 1;

    var a = (segment[0].lat() != segment[1].lat())?(segment[1].lng() - segment[0].lng())/(segment[1].lat() - segment[0].lat()):inf;
    var b = (segment[0].lat() != p.lat()) ? (p.lng() - segment[0].lng())/(p.lat() - segment[0].lat()):inf;

    return (b > a)?1:0;
}

Maps.ui.getBounds = function() {
    //Lets make a box
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    //Get all the points lines of the polly
    var paths = Maps.area.getPaths();
    for (var p = 0; p < paths.getLength(); p++)
        //To store each path
        var path = paths.getAt(p);
        //Now lets expand the box
        for (var i = 0; i < path.getLength(); i++)
            //Add each point of the line to the 'box' making it bigger each time
            bounds.extend(path.getAt(i));
    //Reaturn the bounds, this has a contains method so we can check if the latLng is in it. 
    return bounds;
}

Array.prototype.max = function() {
  return Math.max.apply(null, this)
}

Array.prototype.min = function() {
  return Math.min.apply(null, this)
}
```

But I can't seem to work it out. For a simple triangle or square it works perfectly, but when we get to something like this it doesn't work because we can't figure out whether `count` should be even or odd

[image]

Comment: Is your polygon always convex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Maps API v3 [spherical geometry](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry) library has the [poly.contains](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#poly). Takes a LatLng and a Polygon and tells you if the point is in the polygon.

```
containsLocation(point:LatLng, polygon:Polygon)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty standard problem for geographical information systems.  There are several "standard" algorithms for solving the problem.  The link below notes a few of them and provides an example.  Note that the algorithms tend to break down in edge cases, such as when the polygon spans the extreme lat/lon boundaries such as the poles and meridian.

[Polygon Algorithms](http://alienryderflex.com/polygon/)